# Executing an action only once - without disable or one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to add some JavaScript code to my page so I can run something only once.

I have a button which has a click event listener and calls a JS function.

```
  <button class="btn btn-warning m-auto">
    Hi! Click me
  </button>
  <h4 style="display"none">Lorem Ipsum</h4>


<script>
    $('button')
      .html('Click me') // Try edit it...
      .on('click', () => $("#myHeader").css("display","block"))
</script>
```

Now, as much as I know, this button will execute and "display" as block that header every time it is clicked. Can I somehow make it to display it only once.
PS: making the button unclickable after it is once clicked is not an option.

EDIT: added a snipped code to this question. As you can see we will get the console.log text every time we click the button. How can we make it to only get executed once.

Like some sort of counter maybe: when it's clicked-counter++, then if counter <=2 console.log("do something else")...

```css
#myH3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test();">Click me</button>
<h3 id="myH3">lorem ipsum</h3>

<script>
  function test() {
    document.getElementById('myH3').style.display = "block";
    console.log("done");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why isn't disabling the button an option?

Comment: Use [`one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one) instead of `on()`

Comment: @Andy, because I use the same button more than one time. So when I click it once, i get a result from some inputs, so when I click it twice, I dont want  to get the second result on top of the first or both the results. I also tried displaying none and block one another but it doesnt do the job.

Comment: If you want to click the button more than once `one` won't help. You'll need set a variable that you can check to see if you should get the input values after the first click.

Comment: @Andy, I get the first values and it works all fine, but when I click it for the second time, the result will just pop up on top of the other. So i want to check it if is clicked more than once at least delete the old result and only show the new one.

Comment: Then simply clear the old result when you click the button and add the new result. No need to check anything.

Comment: Since I was working with D3js I just had to add `d3.select("#element").selectAll("*").remove();`
So it basically "deleted" my old result and let space for the new one to appear. Thank you btw.